# Uinput and Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, uinput

I tried to ask this question on the Raspberry Pi forums, but I have received no responses at all.  I thought I might query the minds of the StackOverflow community that has been so helpful in the past.

I'm writing a userspace driver for the Raspberry Pi (specifically, may be ported to other platforms later) which makes use of the bcm2835 library (GPIO) and uinput (Linux user-input virtual devices). I need to read GPIO pins and translate their values into simulated keypresses on a virtual keyboard. The GPIO part has been completed, and the translation part is also completed. Unfortunately, the virtual-keyboard part has not been solved. Uinput refuses to cooperate.

Now, the exact same code works perfectly on a Debian desktop machine.  The `evdev` and `uinput` modules are required, both of which were loaded in all test cases.  On the desktop, inputs can be triggered, however, on the Raspberry Pi, I can verify that the GPIO subsystem has registered the input, but the uinput events do not trigger.  Does anyone have a lead on what I might do?

Thank you very much, if you need any information, logs, or otherwise, please let me know and I will post them as soon as I can.

Comment: A really interesting question, but it's so specific that I think you'd have better luck asking on a #Linux IRC channel.

Comment: @jpaugh, Yes, that would be best.

Answer (score 0):

This is a complete solution that works for me. I have a custom-made keypad and these are the keys I have defined. [Here](https://robocup.wtb.tue.nl/svn/techunited/trunk/dev/GeertJan/scrum_and_bump/vel_estim/mouse_input/documents/Getting%20started%20with%20uinput_%20the%20user%20level%20input%20subsystem.pdf) is the link to original pdf I used.
Of course you can define whatever key you want, just add  it to the array.

Note: this code only works with elevated permission.

```
int allowed_keys[allowed_KEYS_size][2] = {0};
void main()
{
   init_keys();
   
   int fd = open_uinput();

   int key_evt = getKeyEVT(49);   // ASCII code for 1
   
   // simulate key press and key release
   emit(fd, EV_KEY, key_evt, 1);
   emit(fd, EV_SYN, SYN_REPORT, 0);
   emit(fd, EV_KEY, key_evt, 0);
   emit(fd, EV_SYN, SYN_REPORT, 0);
}

long int emit(int fd, int type, int code, int val)
{    
    struct input_event ie;

    ie.type = type;
    ie.code = code;
    ie.value = val;
    /* timestamp values below are ignored */
    ie.time.tv_sec = 0;
    ie.time.tv_usec = 0;

    long int y = write(fd, &ie, sizeof(ie));
    return y;
}
int open_uinput()
{
    int fdui = open("/dev/uinput", O_WRONLY | O_NONBLOCK);
    if (fdui < 0)
    {
        printf("uinput fd creation failed!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    ioctl(fdui, UI_SET_EVBIT, EV_KEY);
    ioctl(fdui, UI_SET_EVBIT, EV_SYN); //added by behzad

    for (int i = 0; i < allowed_KEYS_size; i++)
        ioctl(fdui, UI_SET_KEYBIT, allowed_keys[i][1]);

    struct uinput_setup usetup;
    memset(&usetup, 0, sizeof(usetup));
    usetup.id.bustype = BUS_USB;
    usetup.id.vendor = 0x1234;  /* sample vendor */
    usetup.id.product = 0x5678; /* sample product */
    strcpy(usetup.name, "My Keypad. Ver 1.1");

    ioctl(fdui, UI_DEV_SETUP, &usetup);
    ioctl(fdui, UI_DEV_CREATE);

    sleep(2);
    return fdui;
}

int getKeyEVT(int k)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < allowed_KEYS_size; i++)
    {
        if (allowed_keys[i][0] == k)
            return allowed_keys[i][1];
    }
    return -1;
}
void init_keys()
{
    //   Reference:
    //      https://www.alt-codes.net/arrow_alt_codes.php
    //      /usr/include/linux/input-event-codes.h    

    allowed_keys[0][0] = 48;    //ASCII     ---> 0
    allowed_keys[0][1] = KEY_0; //LINUX

    allowed_keys[1][0] = 49;    //ASCII
    allowed_keys[1][1] = KEY_1; //LINUX

    allowed_keys[2][0] = 50;    //ASCII
    allowed_keys[2][1] = KEY_2; //LINUX

    allowed_keys[3][0] = 51;    //ASCII
    allowed_keys[3][1] = KEY_3; //LINUX
}
```